# Examples of unbounded operators whose kernels are not closed

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Please provide some examples of unbounded operators on Hilber space whose kernels are not closed. If the range is not finite dimensional, it would be better.

Comment: $f\times \mathrm{id} : H\times H \to \Bbb C\times H$ where $f$ is an arbitrary unbounded linear map. The range is $\Bbb C\times H$, the kernel is $\ker(f)\times\{0\}$.